# Setting up GitHub Repo with Netbeans IDE

Tags: git, netbeans, github, versioning

I would like to be able to setup my GitHub repo to integrate with my Netbeans project. I'm a super noob at versioning in general, so this may be a pretty easy question. Any help would be appreciated!

*My question is*: What do I insert as my Repository URL?

Here are the options I'm given when I try to push to remote:

[image: Netbeans Options]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to initialize a git repository in your existing project then you can push using the ssh protocol and git@github.com:Username/repositoryname.git it should ask you for your private key file select it from .ssh in your user folder

Comment: Went with command line instead. Thanks! (For those coming later, he helped me in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10185/discussion-between-learath2-and-kentcdodds)

Answer (score 1):

The remote repository location refers to somewhere outside of the local repository that you would like to push to. This can be any of those protocols listed (i.e., you can "push" to a local repository on the disk, or somewhere on the internet). A popular remote repository service for git is [Github](http://github.com). Creating a Github account and using it as the remote allows you to push your changes to their server, and make use of their services associated with git.

Using a remote is not necessary, however. If you want to have your source code only on your local machine, then there is no need to add remotes. In that case, use the first radio option. You may need to initialize the git repository if you haven't yet. To do that, visit the directory of your project and run `git init` (assumes you have git installed).