# Git can't clone repository

Tags: git

I'm trying to connect to a repository but I always get this message when I try to connect

```
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 c1:90:ff:d5:6b:78:33:5d:7b:ba:f6:f6:bc:1c:de:79
Connection abandoned.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Is your public key on the host server?

Comment: yes I added my public key to my account on the host server

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166173/git-servers-host-key-not-cached-in-registry-github-com

Regards,
Udi

Comment: I'm on a windows system so sudo won't do it

Comment: @Udi Cohen I tryed it already but it will not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ssh is not working for you try to clone using http/https.

Another solution (depends on your git "server" github/bitbucket/stash etc) add your ssh key to the "server" and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Try to manually connect to the host with ssh to confirm and store the ssh fingerprint. On Windows it might help to use a tool for the checkout that can handle this for you. Eclipse for example can, as far as I know.

Comment: Not quite an answer... More of a comment

Comment: And how do you do this?

Comment: if you are on linux : ssh username@server. If you are on windows... use linux.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Very helpful for Windows users, indeed :-( 
To stevedc If you're using Windows, you need to install a SSH client (e.g. Putty) and use that.