# Git SSH Issue on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, git, ssh, bitbucket

I have set up my ssh key in `~/.ssh` and tested it on another PC (working)

`ssh` to `git@bitbucket.org`  **OK**

`ssh` to `bitbucket.org` **FAIL**

`git clone` form  `git@bitbucket.org:account/gmc.git` **FAIL**

Any idea what is happening in this case and I am not able to git clone ?

```
user@pc //server/users$/user
$ ssh git@bitbucket.org
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
logged in as thedev.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
Connection to bitbucket.org closed.
```

---

```
user@pc //server/users$/user
$ ssh bitbucket.org
Permission denied (publickey).
```

---

```
user@pc //server/users$/user
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:account/gmc.git
Cloning into 'gmc'...
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
Connection abandoned.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

know_hosts file

```
bitbucket.org,131.103.20.167 ssh-rsa abc...==
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was conflict between Open SSH and PLINK.exe (used by putty)

Details here:
[Git server's host key not cached in registry - GitHub.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166173/git-servers-host-key-not-cached-in-registry-github-com)

Got it working by changing the `GIT_SSH` env var to `/usr/bin/ssh.exe` and now using openssh.