# git push origin master = permission denied ( publickey )

Tags: git

I am new to git. I had already create key millions time but still have the error

how can I wipe out the old new and create the new one from scratch. It has been a day but I still could not figure this out.

1. I have to access my co-worker

   git@github.com:hisuser/one.git
2. I was able to do clone and push before , but had no idea how I lost the permission.
3. I googled and it recommend me to do

   ssh-keygen -t rsa

but it still not working can someone help guide me how to push my new file to the location. ?

Comment: Can you work through these steps and report back how far you get https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: when I did ssh-add -l  " could not open a connection to your authentication agent " , but I was able to see connection to port 22

Comment: Can you try this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147521/setting-up-repo-on-github-error-on-push-u-origin-master in specific `ssh -T git@github.com` and `exec ssh-agent bash`

Comment: Here is a [Guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) to do it properly. Follow it step by step and it should work for you. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely try using `ssh-add` to add keys to the agent. You can have multiple key files attached to your ssh agent.

```
man ssh-add  
ssh-add /path/to/file.rsa
```

Comment: `ssh-add -l` first to see if you have any keys stored.